# Illegal Instruction (core dumped) with Tensorflow 1.5

Tags: php, python, ubuntu, tensorflow

I have a python script for running a tensorflow model, and I need to run this script from a PHP file (for complicated reasons) using the PHP `shell_exec` function.  When I run the python file with the following code:

```
$command = 'cd testModels/crosswalkPredict && . activate keras && python test_script.py';
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

I get the following error: `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`

I read that the issue typcally occurs when the CPU doesn't support instructions that are present in newer versions of Tensorflow. So I downgraded to Tensorflow 1.5.

However, this error does not occur when I run `cd testModels/crosswalkPredict && . activate keras && python test_script.py` directly from the terminal; it only occurs when I run it from within the PHP `shell_exec` function.

I have gone as far as to try the python script with only the following lines:

```
import tensorflow
print('Hello!')
```

It still gives the same error, so I know the issue occurs  when all I'm doing is importing tensorflow and running the script with `shell_exec`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: are you able to run any other shell command? try `ls -la` for example

Comment: I can run other shell commands with no problem.  I only ran into errors when running scripts that use tensorflow/keras.

Comment: For exmaple, in the minimized script with the print(Hello), if I comment out the "import tensorflow" line, everything works perfectly.

Comment: where is your `testModels` folder is located? does it belong to your php project? try to replace that part with full path to your file

Comment: My PHP file, called `crosswalkPredict.php`, is located in `/home/user01/Desktop/transportation`, and my testModels folder is located in the same directory (`/home/user01/Desktop/transportation`).

Comment: You might want to check the limits applied to the PHP processes (not php.ini, but otuside of PHP). Tensorflow is known to crash in case it runs out of memory. Check

Comment: @UweOhse What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: save this into a .php file and call it with a browser: <?php print "<pre>".shell_exec("ulimit -a")."</pre>";

Comment: time(seconds)        unlimited,  
file(blocks)         unlimited,  
data(kbytes)         unlimited,  
stack(kbytes)        8192,  
coredump(blocks)     0,  
memory(kbytes)       unlimited,  
locked memory(kbytes) 16384,  
process              15532,  
nofiles              1024,  
vmemory(kbytes)      unlimited,  
locks                unlimited,  
rtprio               0,

Comment: The limits should be okay. Can you rule out file access right problems?

Comment: I think so.  I am able to run the same script through `shell_exec` when the `import tensorflow` is commented out, and the script runs just fine, so I would imagine that file permissions aren't a problem.

Comment: Does the user running PHP (www-data or so) have write permissions where tensorflow wants to write to?

Comment: @UweOhse Yes it does.

Comment: Are you runing TensorFlow through a python virtual environment ? If yes, is it using the same python version as your OS ? (shell_exec() will use your default python version)

Comment: @MohamedAyoubBENJELLOUN I am running TensorFlow through a python virtual environment.  One thing that I just noticed is that when I run python through the command line, it uses python 3.6.7, whereas when I run it through `shell_exec()`, it uses python 3.7.0.  Could this be an issue?

Comment: It could, can you invoke python through shell_exec() using the binary path of the 3.6 instead of the python alias who is pointing at the 3.7 and see if it fixes the issue ? Example: shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3.6 toto.py'); // instead of shell_exec('python toto.py');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  as I mentioned in a couple of the comments, I am using a python virtual environment.  When I was executing the python script from the command line, the python interpreter from within the python virtual environment was being used, and everything was fine.  Whenever I executed the script rom `shell_exec`, the default installation of the python interpreter was being used, and this was where the error occurred.

I am not very experienced in using python virtual environments, so that is likely why it took so long for me to arrive at an understanding of the problem.  Luckily, MohammedAyoubBENJELLOUN's comment about shell_exec using the default python installation put me on the right path, and I figured it out from there.

To solve this problem, I simply invoked the python interpreter at the path of the interpreter inside of the python virtual environment instead of trying to activate the virtual environment and then executing.

For example, I used:

```
/home/user01/anaconda3/envs/keras/bin/python test_script.py
```

Instead of:

```
. activate keras && python test_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a known TensorFlow compatibility issue with AVX support on older CPU, it could be fixed if you compile TensorFlow from the sources:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17411#issuecomment-386888244

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17411#issuecomment-420157421

Comment: If I try to run a python script that uses TensorFlow, and I run it directly from the command line, it runs perfectly, while if I run it using `shell_exec()`, I get the error.  If I don't get the error when running it from the command line, would it still be possible that it's a CPU compatibility issue?